# MySQL query 193 hours running and counting... what to do?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Our MySQL always ends up in this state at some point... `SHOW PROCESSLIST` shows nothing in the queue, so why does this say it's been running for 193 hours?

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                                                           
 2785 mysql     20   0  133m  45m 5808 S    6  0.3 193:58.50 mysqld
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misinterpreted the TIME+ field. That is not how long it's been "running for", that is a figure of used CPU time. Check out this Wikipedia article for specifics: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_time

Comment: Also, that is the MySQL daemon that has used up a total of 194 hours of CPU time for all the work it has done, rather than a single query execution time, which is what the title of the question seems to imply!